# Popup in WFS layer Openlayers

Tags: popup, openlayers, layer

Good Morning.

To work with wfs layer is it better to use leaflet or openlayers?

I have a code with openlayers that returns WFS from the geoserver. But I'm not able to show the attributes in popup. can anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have data displayed from a WFS source as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html and you want to click on a feature as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html and display attributes?

Comment: That's right. I can show WFS on the map, but I don't know how to click on a point and popup the attribute values.

Comment: A solution such as https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-wfs-forked-kh80i would work with any vector layer regardless of the source.  To avoid third party libraries it uses a CSS defined popup as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html

Comment: I don't know how to get from the WFS layer the features to show in the popup

Comment: `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel()` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel finds vector features where you clicked.  If you have multiple vector layers you can use a layer filter function to restrict it to you WFS layer.

Comment: I tried using map.forEachFeatureAtPixel() and it didn't work. Does not show popup

Comment: It works in the codesandbox if you click on one of the features.  What happens if you substitute the WFS url for your WFS?

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I'm going to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ol-ext ol/Overlay/PopupFeature to display feature attributes in a popup.
See example: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.popup.feature.html

Comment: I posted my code following this link. Can you help me?

Comment: Hello good afternoon. Can you help me with the code? I followed the link you indicated. Inside the popup it shows 'undefined'. I don't know what it could be. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following the example of https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.popup.feature.html, I have this code where my WFS layer contains the id and name attributes, however, it doesn't show anything in the popup

```
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url: function(extent) {
            return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/teste/wfs?service=WFS&' +
              version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=teste:MYLAYER&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
              'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
        });
 
 
        var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
                    width: 2
                })
            })
        });
               
        var layers = [
            new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()}),
            vector,
        ];
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: layers,
             interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate:false, pinchRotate:false }),
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-46.444137, -23.713596]),
                zoom: 12
            })
        });
        
  var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    hitTolerance: 5,
    multi: true,
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick
  });
 map.addInteraction(select);

  var popup = new ol.Overlay.PopupFeature({
    popupClass: 'default anim',
    select: select,
    canFix: true,
    template: {
        title: 
          function(f) {
            return f.get('nome')+' ('+f.get('id')+')';
          },
        attributes: // [ 'id', 'nome' ]
        {
          'nome': { title: 'Nome' },
          'id': { title: 'Id' },
        
        }
    }
  });
 map.addOverlay (popup);
```

Comment: Here is a working exemple: https://codepen.io/viglino/pen/WNpaeag

Comment: You don't have to set the popup template, if none it will show all attributes.
When fix you can try to set the popup title and the attributes you want to see in the popup with a template...

Comment: Thanks @ViglinoJean-Marc. I followed the example codepen.io/viglino/pen/WNpaeag and managed to see a popup. One question: is it possible in the popup to show an image or a link to a page with a mask or even a frame?

Comment: You can use a template to format the attributes as an HTML image or a link as well:
```
 var popup = new ol.Overlay.PopupFeature({
  popupClass: 'default anim',
  canFix: true,
  select: select,
  template: {
    attributes: {
      'img': { format: function(val) { return '<img src="'+val+'" />'; }}
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @ViglinoJean-Marc Thank you. I'm going to try and I'm going to say if it worked or not. Thanks for sharing your code and helping me with questions.

Comment: @ViglinoJean-Marc Is it possible to create a popup for each layer? For example, in one layer I have an ID attribute that I want to show as ID, another layer has ID but I don't want to show it, and in other cases I have ID but I want to show it as code. It's possible? Thanks

Comment: The template option can be a function that returns a template. So you can choose what to show on the fly.

Comment: @ViglinoJean-Marc In this case, if I have 3 layers: layer1, layer2 and layer3. How do I specify in the template which layer I'm setting attributes for? For layer 1, ID I want to show as ID. For layer 2 I want to show the ID as CODE and for other layers I don't want to show the ID attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the popup code. I have 3 layers: layer1, layer2 and layer3.
For layer1, ID I want to show as ID. For layer2, I want to show ID as CODE and for other layers I don't want to show ID attribute.
How should I change the template? Thanks

```
 var popup = new ol.Overlay.PopupFeature({
    popupClass: 'default anim',
    select: select_interaction,
    canFix: true,
    template: {
        title: 
            function(f) {
                return f.get('NAME')+' ('+f.get('ID')+')';
            },
        attributes: 
        {
            'ID': { title: 'ID' },
            // with prefix and suffix
            'POP': { 
                title: 'População',  // attribute's title
                before: '',           // something to add before
                format: ol.Overlay.PopupFeature.localString(),  // format as local string
                after: ' hab.'        // something to add after
            }, 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @ViglinoJean-Marc Can you help me?

Comment: You have to use a function that returns the template you want to use depending on the feature attributes...

Comment: @ViglinoJean-Marc I did not understand. Is it possible to create a template for each layer? If yes, how? thank you me

Answer (score 0):

@user12538529
You have to create a function and return the template for each case:

```js
// Create templates
var templateID = { ... }; 
var templateCODE = { ... };
// Popup with a template function
var popup = new ol.Overlay.PopupFeature({
    popupClass: 'default anim',
    select: select_interaction,
    canFix: true,
    template: function(feature) {
      var prop = feature.getProperties();
      // Test if has property ID
      if (prop.hasOwnProperty('ID')) return templateID;
      // or property CODE
      else if (prop.hasOwnProperty('CODE')) return templateCODE;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of testing the attribute, eg ID, CODE, can I test if it is layer1, layer2, layer3, etc? Because in several layers I have ID, but in one, I'll show it as ID, in another, as Code, and in others I might want not to show it. I'd like to build a template for each layer I'm going to add. It's possible?

Comment: You only have access to the feature not the layer but you can register the layer on add: `layer.getSource ().on('addfeature', function (f){ f.layer = layer; })` the you can acess features layer...